# El evento onLoad (imagen) desincronizado ¿Cómo evitarlo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos

Me está ocurriendo lo que yo creo que es una desicronización (delay o retraso) al cargar imagenes:

Tengo estos elementos:

```
<input type="file" id="file">
<img id="img1">
<img id="img2">
```

Al cargar el priner archivo todo va perfecto:

```
    $("#file").change(function(e)
    {
        var imgObj = e.target.files[0]; 

        var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL;
        imgObj.src = url.createObjectURL(imgObj);

        $("#img1").attr("src",imgObj.src);          
        this.val("")
     });

    $("#img1").on("load", function(e)
    {
       $("#img2").attr("src",this.src)
    }
```

Pero al cargarse el segundo archivo a veces falla y en "img2" en vez de cargarse la segunda imagen se carga la primera.

Creo que es un problema de sincronización o algo así porque al poner un console,log("texto) de esta forma:

```
    $("#img1").on("load", function(e)
    {
        console.log("texto");
       $("#img2").attr("src",this.src)
    }
```

Empeza a funcionar correctamente. Lo que pienso es que al poner console.log("texto") anetes transcurre cierto tiempo... tiepo suficiente como para que la variable "this.src" sea seteada con el nuevo valor.

Sea como fuese es un compartamiento totalmente indeseable. 
¿Alguien sabe como lo puedo evitar que esto suceda?

Comment: Ok..[aquí](https://jsbin.com/jikuqim/edit?html,js,output) he creado un ejemplo y funciona a la perfección...

Comment: Si, el tuyo funciona estupendamente. Ojalá el mio funcionara así tambien!! ¿ por qué me puede estar pasando esto?

Comment: Buena pregunta... revisa bien el código paso a paso (breakpoints en consola)... las dependencias... el cache... etc

Comment: Voy con ello a ver si hay suerte... Gracias!!

Comment: ya di con el problema, pero no con la solución... era por culpa de "pica"... yo borraba la imagen pero se mantenia en memoria ¿Por casualidad no sabrás usar la libreria pica? necesito acceder a un [object CanvasRenderingContext2D] que usa esta libreria para poder borrar el contenido de un canvas.